# What is the proper way to load JavaScript scripts in Atom Shell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

This probably a completely stupid question but I just started working with Atom shell.

I have an `index.html` with a login form. I boostrap the jquery form validation in the document ready like so:

```js
 $(function() {
     $('#login-form').validate();
 });
```

This script is loaded just before the body ends like so:

```html
<script src="global/js/dom-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

When I run the page with Atom Shell the form shows up properly and the validation works partially. It does not submit the form but it doesn't show any validation. Then when I submit the form once staying on the same page (e.g., reload the page) everything works just fine!

Same goes with including Bootstrap's `tab.js`. At first it does not work but, after a page reload it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my `main.js` (based on Atom Shell example from Github):

```js
var app = require('app');  // Module to control application life.
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');  // Module to create native browser window.

// Report crashes to our server.
require('crash-reporter').start();

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the javascript object is GCed.
var mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin')
    app.quit();
});


// This method will be called when atom-shell has done everything
// initialization and ready for creating browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    icon                : 'global/images/logo.png',
    transparent         : true,
    frame               : false,
    "min-width"         : 520,
    "min-height"        : 850,
    fullscreen          : true,
    resize              : true,
    "use-content-size"  : true
  });

  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {

  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Comment: 1. have you loaded jQuery before your script in `index.html`?

2. remove the empty 'did-finish-load' listener/handler

3. are you getting any errors/console output on either the renderer or browser side?

4. what is your `validate` method doing? can we see that code?

5. the rest of your client scripts that are related please

Comment: Some scripts, like bootstrap maybe, look for the presence of 'require' as a way to detect if they are running in a browser or in node or in a browserified way. Since electron is a browser but also has require it can sometimes cause these scripts to fail to load. Sometimes you can just require them from a script block instead of load them like this and then it will work as expected.